# Yii - Event not fired because the module class is not loaded

Tags: php, yii, yii-events

I am trying to register an event from within a module. So, I added this couple of lines in the init function of my module class (`protected/modules/points/PointsModule.php`).

```
class PointsModule extends CWebModule {
    public function init() {
        ...
        // Attach the "User Register" event
        Yii::app()->user->onUserRegister = array($this, "addPointsForRegistration");
        die('init');
        }
    ...
}
```

I only see the result of the `die('init')` when I use the module controller. Any other page of my application won't do anything.

I import the file in `config/main.php` file

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.modules.points.*',
),
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. The file seems to be not loaded at all if I am not using the module's controller.
Is there a way to load a module class (or another component) at each page load in yii? Is there a cleaner way to register an event from inside a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Module instance is created only if you use this particular *module*, same applies to `init` method. So, when you access different module event is not attached, even more, other modules are not aware of this, because they have no information that anything global should be registered.

But you use `user` component - which is guaranteed to run. You could register event onUserRegister (in `user` component) to call some method, prefably not from module, but from something lighter, maybe some `Points` model? Of course this breaks modularity, because if you remove `PointsModule` it will break `user` component.

Maybe you could attach it in config i'm using following config for application component:

```
'onBeginRequest' => function()
     {
         YII_DEBUG? : ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
     }
```

Something like:

```
'user' => [
    'onUserRegister' => function()
    {
        // Handle event here
    }
]
```

Side note: Cross module or more generally cross component interaction migth be tricky. I'm developing [extension](https://github.com/Maslosoft/YiiSignals) for this purpose, idea is to aggregate events from whole application and fire them when needed.

Comment: Thanks fo your answer, I'll have a look on your extension it may help me a lot!